# Where to run continuous jobs on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a job that involves continuously listening to one or more websocket/mqtt feeds and forwarding this data to an event queue. This job is written in javascript and would run 24/7 in a continuous loop.

The most obvious solution is to run this job on a VM with Compute Engine, but I was wondering is there is a more elegant solution. Azure, for example, has WebJobs that's well-suited to this kind of task. It even restarts the script if there is an error.

Is there some other component on GCP that can run this job in a "managed" way?

Comment: Would [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview) do what you need?

Comment: Not really. Cloud functions are good for event-based workloads, but I don't see that mapping to my infinite loop model at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud does not have a product similar to Azure WebJobs at the moment. Both the standard and flexible environments of Google Cloud App Engine do not currently support websockets. In order to use websockets you can use [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs) or [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs).